# Gathering in MPI, but not with MPI_Gather

Tags: c, mpi

I need to do something like an MPI_Gather, but I need to store the gathered data in an order that depends on something different from process rank.  I thought I could do something like this:

```
int i;
int gathervals[10];
int my_val, my_place_in_storage;

/* init MPI etc ... then ... */

my_val = some_fcn_of_rank(my_rank, ...)
my_place_in_storage = some_other_fcn(my_val, my_rank, ...)

if (my_rank == 0){
/* my_val on proc 0 does go in gathervals[0], which simplifies
   things */
   gathervals[0] = my_val;
   for (i=1; i<num_procs; i++){
      MPI_Recv(&gathervals[i], 1, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE,
               i, MPI_COMM_WORLD, stat_mpi);
   }
}else{
   MPI_Send(&mv_val, 1, MPI_INT, 0, my_place_in_storage,
            MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}
```

My thinking is that proc 0 will start the loop and wait until a Send is posted from the proc whose `my_place_in_storage` is 1, then proc 0 will receive that message and put the value into `gathervals[1]`.  Then it will iterate and wait until it sees a post from the proc whose `my_place_in_storage` is 2, etc.

Should this work?  I'm getting a seg fault on proc 0 and I'm trying to figure out why.  I thought this block of code, which might be a little unorthodox, would be the place to start.  I have verified the correctness of all the `my_place_in_storage` values.

Comment: If you encounter a segfault - or another bug, please post an [mcve].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this should work, but you there is a better alternative. Use `MPI_Gather` to collect `my_place_in_storage` and use it as displacement array for `MPI_Gatherv`. Something along the lines:

```
 if (my_rank == 0) {
     int displacements[10];
     int recvcounts[10] = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1};
     MPI_Gather(&my_place_in_storage, 1, MPI_INT,
                displacements, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD); 
     MPI_Gatherv(&my_val, 1, MPI_INT, gathervals, recvcounts,
                 displacements, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
 } else {
     MPI_Gather(&my_place_in_storage, 1, MPI_INT,
                NULL, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD); 
     MPI_Gatherv(&my_val, 1, MPI_INT, NULL, 1, NULL,
                 MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
 }
```

In general, it is better to use a collective instead of multiple point to point messages. This is more scalable and allows more optimizations by the MPI implementation.

Comment: The `recvcounts` parameter in the first call to `MPI_Gatherv` should be `recvcounts`, not `1`.

Answer (score 5):

The other option is to use MPI_Comm_split to create a new communicator which contains all the same processes as MPI_COMM_WORLD but permuted into a new order based on "my_place_in_storage". You could do this if everyone supplied the same value of "color" so they all belonged to the same communicator, but used "my_place_in_storage" as the "key".

Communicator creation has some overhead but this might be more efficient overall than using two gathers if you do this operation many times with the same values of "my_place_in_storage". Note that, in the new communicator, you would also just use gather which should also be faster than gatherv.

Comment: Interesting.  I would not have thought of that.  Thanks!